# Angular test fails to run with ChromeHeadlessCI in Github Action

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, github-actions

I bootstrap a simple Angular (v10.1) app and create Github action workflow as below. Note that I have configured test to run with recommended configurations as specified in [Angular Testing doc](https://angular.io/guide/testing#set-up-continuous-integration)

```yml
# ./github/workflows/main.yml
name: Test master branch

on:
  push:
    branches: [master]
  pull_request:
    branches: [master]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.10]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - name: Cache Node.js modules
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          # npm cache files are stored in `~/.npm` on Linux/macOS
          path: ~/.npm
          key: ${{ runner.OS }}-node-${{ hashFiles('**/yarn.lock') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.OS }}-node-
            ${{ runner.OS }}-
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Run lint
        run: npm lint
      - name: Run tests
        run: npm test -- --no-watch --no-progress --browsers=ChromeHeadlessCI
```

The test fails with error `Cannot load browser "ChromeHeadlessCI": it is not registered! Perhaps you are missing some plugin?`.
The same error is thrown even if I try running `npm test -- --no-watch --no-progress --browsers=ChromeHeadlessCI` on local computer.

```sh
$ npm test -- --no-watch --no-progress --browsers=ChromeHeadlessCI

> sampleapp-frontend@0.0.0 test C:\sampleapp\sampleapp-frontend
> ng test "--no-watch" "--no-progress" "--browsers=ChromeHeadlessCI"

12 09 2020 21:33:13.888:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v5.0.9 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
12 09 2020 21:33:13.892:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers ChromeHeadlessCI with concurrency unlimited
12 09 2020 21:33:13.894:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot load browser "ChromeHeadlessCI": it is not registered! Perhaps you are missing some plugin?
12 09 2020 21:33:13.895:ERROR [karma-server]: Error: Found 1 load error
    at Server.<anonymous> (C:\sampleapp\sampleapp-frontend\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:189:27)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:420:28)
    at Server.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at emitListeningNT (net.js:1351:10)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:21)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

How can I fix this issue with `ChromeHeadlessCI`?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Be sure to check that the following items are in `karma.conf.js`:

```
browsers: ['Chrome', 'ChromeHeadless', 'ChromeHeadlessCI'],
customLaunchers: {
  ChromeHeadlessCI: {
    base: 'ChromeHeadless',
    flags: ['--no-sandbox']
  }
},
```

This will help the launcher find ChromeHeadlessCI.

Comment: Unfortunately, did not solve my problem. Any other ideas?

Comment: This cause a chrome-gui to launch and is there for unsuited to CI setup by itself.

Answer (score 6):

The above answers seem incomplete to me. Here's a working example:

## 1. Install dependencies

We use `puppeteer` to call & manage the headless-chrome instance.
We also install `karma-chrome-launcher` to provide the plugin for Karma.

Run `npm i -D puppeteer karma-chrome-launcher` to install both.

## 2. Configure Karma

Three more code lines and we're good to go.

- We pass a headless-chrome instance to the system via `puppeteer`:

```js
process.env.CHROME_BIN = require('puppeteer').executablePath()
```

- Import the installed Karma plugin

```js
require('karma-chrome-launcher')]
```

- Finally, add `ChromeHeadless` to the list of available browsers:

```js
browsers: ['ChromeHeadless', 'Firefox']
```

### How karma.conf.js might look now:

```js
// karma.conf.js
process.env.CHROME_BIN = require('puppeteer').executablePath() // IMPORTANT!

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadless', 'Firefox'], // IMPORTANT! You can list & use multiple browsers
    plugins: [
        require('karma-jasmine'),
        require('karma-chrome-launcher')], // IMPORTANT!
        require('karma-firefox-launcher'),
        ...
    ],
    ...
  })
}
```

## 3. Execute!

Execute `ng test --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadless` & enjoy your tests!
I've added an alias inside `package.json` that I call via `npm run test-headless` in my GitHub Action.

```json
"scripts": {
    ...,
    "test-headless": "ng test --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadless",
    ...
```

When on desktop, I use Firefox via `ng test --browsers=Firefox`.

---

Sources:

- https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher
- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/headless-karma-mocha-chai (More in depth info about puppeteer)

Comment: Worked for me, thanks! Angular 13 with karma.

Answer (score 5):

You didn't mention any modifications to `karma.conf.js` and you probably should add this there:

```
browsers: ['Chrome'],
customLaunchers: {
  ChromeHeadlessCI: {
    base: 'ChromeHeadless',
    flags: ['--no-sandbox']
  }
},
```

https://angular.io/guide/testing#configure-cli-for-ci-testing-in-chrome

If that won't be enough you probably will have to install chrome/chromium on your testing environment.